# How to merge rows (with strings) based on column value (int) in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have datasets in the format

```
df1=
 userid movieid    tags                     timestamp

    73  130682  b movie                     1432523704  
    73  130682  comedy                      1432523704  
    73  130682  horror                      1432523704  
    77  1199    Trilogy of the Imagination  1163220043  
    77  2968    Gilliam                     1163220138  
    77  2968    Trilogy of the Imagination  1163220039  
    77  4467    Trilogy of the Imagination  1163220065  
    77  4911    Gilliam                     1163220167  
    77  5909    Takashi Miike               1163219591
```

and I want another dataframe to be in format

```
df2=

userid    tags
73       b movie[1] comedy[1] horror[1]
77       Trilogy of the Imagination[3] Gilliam[1] Takashi Miike[1]
```

such that I can merge all tags together for word/s count or term frequency.
In sort, I want all tags for one userid together concatenated by " " (one space), such that I can also count number of occurrences of word/s.  I am unable to concatenate strings in tags together. I can count words and its occurrences. Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First count and reformat the result of the count per group. Keep it as an intermediate result:

```
r = df.groupby('userid').apply(lambda g: g.tags.value_counts()).reset_index(level=-1)
r
Out[46]: 
                           level_1  tags
userid                                  
73                         b movie     1
73                          horror     1
73                          comedy     1
77      Trilogy of the Imagination     3
77                         Gilliam     2
77                   Takashi Miike     1
```

This simple string manipulation will give you the result per line:

```
r.level_1+'['+r.tags.astype(str)+']'
Out[49]: 
userid
73                       b movie[1]
73                        horror[1]
73                        comedy[1]
77    Trilogy of the Imagination[3]
77                       Gilliam[2]
77                 Takashi Miike[1]
```

The neat part of being in Python is to be able to do something like this with it:

```
(r.level_1+'['+r.tags.astype(str)+']').groupby(level=0).apply(' '.join)
Out[50]: 
userid
73                       b movie[1] horror[1] comedy[1]
77    Trilogy of the Imagination[3] Gilliam[2] Takas...
```